# How to overlay two Rasters using ifelse (Conditional Statements) in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, overlay, raster

I have two rasters (images), and want to overlay them using this code:

```
# Getting the images
library(raster)

URL1 <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/6jjz7ou1skz88wr/raster_1.tif?dl=1"
URL2 <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5xuixohjqfnfze/raster_2.tif?dl=1"

download.file(URL1, destfile=paste0(getwd(),"/", "raster_1.tif"), method="auto", mode="wb", timeout="6000")
download.file(URL2, destfile=paste0(getwd(),"/", "raster_2.tif"), method="auto", mode="wb", timeout="6000")

# Reading the images 
raster_1 <- raster(list.files(pattern="raster_1.tif$"))
raster_2 <- raster(list.files(pattern="raster_2.tif$"))

# Overlaying
myFun <- function(x,y){ifelse(x==0 && y==0, 0, ifelse(x==1 && y==0, 2, ifelse(x==1 && y>0, y)))}

( res <- overlay(stack(raster_1 ,raster_2), fun = Vectorize(myFun) ) )

### R gives this error
Error in .overlayList(x, fun = fun, filename = filename, forcefun = forcefun,  : 
  cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a function that only uses vectorized operators. This is case where Boolean arithmetic should both succeed and be more efficient

```
myFun <- function(x,y){ 0*(x==0 && y==0)+ 
                        2*(x==1 && y==0)+
                        y*(x==1 && y>0) }
```

There are some edge cases that do not appear covered. Can `x` ever be a value other than exactly 0 or 1? Can `y` ever be negative?

After running my version I get:

```
> ( res <- overlay(stack(raster_1 ,raster_2), fun = Vectorize(myFun) ) )
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 2958, 1642, 4857036  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 500, 500  (x, y)
extent      : -171063.8, 649936.2, 5317253, 6796253  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=12 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0, 14751  (min, max)
```

I didn't think I would need to use `Vectorize` around `myFun`,`enter code here` but the results seems more likely to be correct when I leave it in the call to `overlay`:

```
> Hmisc::describe(values(res))
values(res) 
       n  missing distinct     Info     Mean      Gmd      .05      .10      .25 
 3222508  1634528     1502    0.727     4918     6403        0        0        0 
     .50      .75      .90      .95 
       0    13898    14082    14168 

Value            0   13000   13200   13400   13600   13800   14000   14200   14400
Frequency  2089448      67     578   10515   69031  249817  523241  226628   46191
Proportion   0.648   0.000   0.000   0.003   0.021   0.078   0.162   0.070   0.014

Value        14600   14800
Frequency     6876     116
Proportion   0.002   0.000
```

When I took out the Vectorize step I did not get an error but I got all zeros, instead.

Comment: Thanks. It was a great help. Appreciate. No, X only has two values (i.e., 0 and 1); and Y can not be negative.

Comment: Is `ifelse` not vectorized for rasters?

Comment: `ifelse` often returns an object with attributes stripped off and it's not a generic function. I think rasters are matrices with special attributes.  The data used in this example is no longer at the Dropbox location so testing is not possible unless a new set of data can be identified. Looking at the origianl code it does appear the `ifelse` function were improperly punctuated so the OP's failure may not be due to `ifelse` behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you really are trying to achieve, and there might be better solutions. In your example data, `Y` (raster_2) has no values of zero. That suggest that you want the values of `raster_2` where `raster_1` is not 0? That can be achieved like this:

```
m <- mask(raster_2, raster_1, maskvalue=0)
```

I think that 42-'s `myFun` has a problem in that it returns 0 when none of the conditions are true, specifically when `(x == 0 & y > 0)`

To make it work with `overlay`, replace the `&&` with `&`

```
myFunV <- function(x,y){ 
                    0*(x==0 & y==0)+ 
                    2*(x==1 & y==0)+
                    y*(x==1 & y>0) }                        

res <- overlay(raster_1, raster_2, fun = myFunV)
```

(but, again, I doubt that this is good approach for your needs)