# R raster construct new raster from two existing rasters

Tags: r, r-raster

I need to construct a new raster (called `ch` based on two rasters (called `tmin` and `tmax`) based on the following logic. Each element of the new raster follows this logic. `tmin, tmax` and `ch` are all raster bricks with identical dimensions but I thought I'd experiment with just single layers first.

```
if (tmin > 7) ch <- 0
if (tmax < 7) ch <- 24
else
ch <- (7 - tmin)/(tmax - tmin)
```

I tried to follow the logic of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56049806/how-to-overlay-two-rasters-using-ifelse-conditional-statements-in-r) with the following code. `testout` consists of zeros or 24s as expected. I can't figure out how to get the last part of the logic into this process.

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster()
r2 <- raster()
set.seed(10)
values(r1) <- runif(ncell(r1), min = 0, max = 10)
values(r2) <- runif(ncell(r2), min = 0, max = 10)

myFun <- function(r1, r2) {
  0*(r1 > 7)+
  24*(r2 < 7)  
}

testout <- myFun(r1, r2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data

```
library(raster)
r1 <- r2 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
set.seed(10)
values(r1) <- runif(ncell(r1), min = 0, max = 10)
values(r2) <- runif(ncell(r2), min = 0, max = 10)
```

Vectorized function

```
myFun <- function(tmin, tmax) {
    ch <- (7 - tmin)/(tmax - tmin)
    ch[tmin > 7] <- 0
    ch[tmax < 7 & tmin <= 7] <- 24
    ch
}

ch1 <- overlay(r1, r2, fun=myFun)
```

Undocumented alternative

```
ifel <- raster:::.ifel
ch2 <- ifel(r1 > 7, 0, ifel(r2 < 7, 24, (7 - r1)/(r2 - r1)))
```